# Is it possible to create an AWS VPS for someone without requiring his credentials?

Tags: amazon-aws

I want to create and configure an AWS VPS for someone. I think that asking for his AWS credentials is too much, because there's sensitive billing information and other things, and also because passwords are not meant to be shared. I could ask for him to create the VM and pass me the SSH login. However, suppose it's a very non technical person. I should only expect him to setup an AWS account with a credit card, not choose VMs RAM, SSD size, CPU cores, etc. I also don't want to maintain the VM on my AWS account, because he is the one who's gonna pay it monthly.

What is the best solution for this problem?